# Locating and checking a check box

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to locate a check box from several checkboxes present and attributes given is `li` and data value only.

How can i locate Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can find element using `By.ByTagName`. Like

```
List<WebElement> list = webDrive.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
WebElement webElement = list.get(3);// assumed 3 li would be required Object.
String str = webElement.getText();
```

It will return you list of li `WebElements`, as List is indexed so you can get your `Item` by index value.

Other you can also locate the element by `XPath`.

```
WebDriver#findElement(By.xpath("xpath expression"));
```

you can use firePath([mozila firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/)) to get the xpath easily.

Comment: Not able to underestand much. Can you please explain your first suggestion in details. How i can store the result and make use of result

Comment: little more explanation by code, hope it would be helpful, in case any question please ask.

Comment: sorry. dont know the concept of list. Lines giving error. New to selenium and Java. Please help